# PHP MVC: Injecting utility/helper class instances into base classes as dependencies

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, model-view-controller, mvvm

In my HMVC project I've implemented an `Arrays` class. Its **STATIC** methods are used overall to handle various operations on multidimensional arrays. Beside this class I use similar ones too: `Files`, `Images`, `Printer`, `Messages`, `Classes`, etc. But I don't want any statics, or singletons in my project anymore.

I see them as helpers, final classes having methods used to just perform specific tasks on the project components or with them (merge arrays, resize images, upload/print files, etc). As such, I want to... minimize their distribution inside my project.

For example, I don't find it optimal to pass an `Arrays` object in each child controller, just because in the constructor of the base controller class some arrays must be merged.

I'd like to ask:

- **Is it wrong that I actually merge arrays inside the base controller class, or this situation can really arise?**
- **If it's not wrong, then I have only the choice to pass the utility class `Arrays` as constructor dependency, and the *static* problem would be elegantly solved this way. Is this true, or is there a better alternative?**

I'd appreciate any perspective of yours.

Thank you very much!

---

P.S:

Here is the `Arrays` class, if you need to take a look in it:

```
<?php

namespace MYMVC\Utils;

/**
 * Arrays: utility class to handle operations on multidimensional arrays.
 */
class Arrays {

    /* ------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /* Keypath format: '{key0}/{key1}/{key2}/{key3}/{searched-key}'. */
    /* ------------------------------------------------------------- */

    /** Set the value in array at the specified keypath. [...] */

    public static function setArrayValue(&$array, $keypath, $value, $delimiter = '/') { ... }


    /** Get a tree structure from the specified keypath. [...] */

    public static function buildArrayTree($keypath, $value, $delimiter = '/') { ... }


    /** Check if the specified keypath exists in array. [...] */

    public static function arrayKeyExists(&$array, $keypath, $delimiter = '/') { ... }


    /** Get the array value from the specified keypath. [...] */

    public static function getArrayValue(&$array, $keypath, $delimiter = '/') { ... }


    /** Merge multiple multidimensional arrays. [...] */

    public static function mergeMultipleArrays(/* func_get_args */) { ... }


    /** Merge the top multidimensional array over the base multidimensional array. [...] */

    public static function mergeArrays($base, $top) { ... }

}
```

Comment: _Should they really be injected?_ - Why they should? Do you need to be able to replace the `Arrays` type with another class? Does `Arrays` require other dependency? Then use it like `Arrays::mergeMultipleArrays` in your classes. That's fine.

Comment: @Federkun Thank you for your answer. Good question of you. I edited my question to somehow reveal what I want to achieve and how I see it. These classes themselves are final classes and don't even ask for any dependencies. Just passive bricks as encapsulations for their methods.

Comment: Since you don't need to customize the usage of your helpers by injecting some dependencies, you can just make one simple function call from your classes to your helpers. You don't have any reason to replace your `Arrays` object with another subtype of that class.

Comment: @Federkun I just realised, that a utility class as `Files` can realy have one or more dependencies (file names, paths, types, etc.). And because I don't want to use _static_ anymore, I must pass it as dependency where it's needed. Can you please give me an anser based on this changes? I'd appreciate it. Thank you. P.S: Unfortunatelly I have no concrete examples to provide for clarity, because I have only use examples from the times when I developed on static systems, earlier. then I just called the helpers statically and all was resolved. Bui I don't want this anymore.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like `Arrays::mergeArrays` is not wrong. You don't mind call `in_array` or `array_merge` inside your classes, no? You can call `Arrays` an "utility" class if you want, but I don't think you can do the same for `Files`.

If your current problem is "I don't want pass the xyz object to each child controller", then usually you have schools of thought:

- Just inject the DIC to your controllers. Then retrieve your dependency from it. That's what's called "Service Locator", and it's widely used by many frameworks. It has the advantage that you can require the dependency only where you need it, and when you need it. But it has a series of downside. Your object can't exists without it, and your classes can't be mocked easily. That's why it's considered an anti-pattern.
- Inject your dependency (i.e: `Files`) explicitly in your controllers. Why you should want hide the fact that your controller depends on `Files`?  The only problem here is, especially with controllers, that many dependencies aren't always used by all the class's methods. That's more a performance problem, and you can think of solve it in many ways (example:
  [Action object](https://github.com/pmjones/adr)).

Choose what works for you.

Comment: I have to say, static, singletons and service locators are a no-go for me. Never ever :-) But I really like the way, how you objectively present them to me as a solution (because they really are one), and in the same time you show me the fact that they are an antipattern. Great answer in this regard. Cont...

Comment: Cont: My real problem is not that I have to inject the utility/helper instances in the base controller (for example), but the fact that I have to merge arrays  (as example) in the base class' constructor. That's were I'm not sure: I don't want to inject something just because I make the wrong decision in regard of arrays merging in constructor. Cont...

Comment: Cont: give me please some minutes to read "Action object" docus and I'll come back.

Comment: Your answer is definitely the proper one. Not only that you gave me a solide and the right perspective and a good recherche resource (I read it already), but you also recognized what my actually problem might be: "_ The only problem here is, especially with controllers, that many dependencies aren't always used by all the class's methods._". Yes how right you are! That bothered me a lot ealier, but I lost the focus on it, beeing occupied with other big parts (simultaneously access to multiple db servers from within my HMVC). Until you made me again aware of it. So, in a word: excelent answer!

Comment: Thank you for your time! I appreciate it. Good luck!